# react can't get attributes in this

Tags: reactjs

[initial code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IG5P6.png)

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
const add='add'
const sub='sub'
const oddAdd='oddAdd'
const AsynAdd='AsynAdd'
export default class Count extends Component {
    state={count:0}
   
    increase=(add)=>{
      console.log(this,this.selectNode,this.state)
        // const{value}=this.selectNode
        
        // const {count}=this.state
        // this.setState({count:count+value*1})
        return (e)=>{
          console.log('after',this,this.selectNode)
          const{value}=this.selectNode
        
          const {count}=this.state
          this.setState({count:count+value*1})
        }
    }
    decrease=()=>{
        
        const{value}=this.selectNode
        
        const {count}=this.state
        this.setState({count:count-value*1})
    }
    increaseOdd=()=>{
        const{value}=this.selectNode
        
        const {count}=this.state
        if(count%2!==0)
        this.setState({count:count+value*1})
    }

    AsynIncrease=()=>{
setTimeout(()=>{const{value}=this.selectNode
        
const {count}=this.state

this.setState({count:count+value*1})},1000)
        
    }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
       <h1>Total sum is {this.state.count}</h1>
       <select  ref={c=>this.selectNode=c}>
        <option value="1">1</option>
        <option value="2">2</option>
        <option value="3">3</option>
       </select>
       <button onClick={this.increase(add)}>increase</button>&nbsp;
       <button onClick={this.decrease}>decrease</button>&nbsp;
       <button onClick={this.increaseOdd}>increase when odd</button>&nbsp;
       <button onClick={this.AsynIncrease}>asynchronize increase</button>
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

[running result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YA8dv.jpg)
just write a very simple program, and seems there is a attribute selectNode, but when I try to print it out, it becomes undefined .
Just curious what's the reason for this, I am not an experienced front-end developer and it really confuses me

Comment: hi. Welcome to StackOverflow. can you please post your code along with error message by editing your question instead of posting image.

Comment: yes. It is my first time to use stack overflow so I am not very familiar with the operations. I have posted the running result of the code above. I have printed out 'this', as you can see, it has attribute selectNode on it. But when I print out this.selectNode, it becomes undefined.

Answer (score 0):

whenever you want to access a prop you need to access it through the props object

```
this.props.selectNode
```

Comment: The code ref={c=>this.selectNode=c} will create a new attribute named selectNode in this. So we can use this.selectNode to access that element. Am I understanding correct?